# Help with $\int{\sin(101x)\sin^{99}(x)}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Here's one that is difficult to solve manually, what is the trick involved?
$$\int \sin(101x)\sin^{99}(x)\,dx$$

Comment: Do you *really* need the indefinite integral or just the value of the integral over some interval? It may be a completely different level of complexity.

Comment: Anyway, for short: $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$ plus the binomial theorem.

Comment: In general, $\displaystyle\int\sin\Big((n+1)x\Big)\sin^{n-1}(x)~dx~=~\frac{\sin(nx)\sin^n(x)}n$

Comment: @Lucian Did you just figure that out, or is it well-known! Either way, I am impressed. I see Mathematica knows it, but it seems worth remembering unless there is some obvious way of "seeing" it.

Comment: One way to see it is to expand $\sin((n+1)x) = \sin(nx)\cos(x) + \cos(nx)\sin(x)$ and notice that you can write the two terms you get on the form $f(x)g'(x) + g(x) f'(x) = (fg)'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This question has been asked several times before:

- [Need help solving - $ \int (\sin 101x) \cdot\sin^{99}x\,dx $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/381867)
- [Evaluate $\Im \bigg (\dfrac{1}{100\times 2^{100}}(e^{2\iota x} -1)^{100}\bigg )$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332650)
- [Integrate $\sin(101x)\cdot \sin^{99}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1598700)